# GWT gin/guice injection order

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-gin

I have a GWT app which uses Gin/Guice.

**My need** : call a method after that all fields are injected.

Here is an extract of Javadoc about [@Inject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html)

```
Constructors are injected first, followed by fields, and then methods.
```

So my idea was to have only one method annotated with `@Inject` and use it as a post-injection method. Here is an extract of my code :

```
//An injected attribute (a JSR 303 validator)
@Inject
private Validator validator;

//A constructor with some injectable args.
@Inject
public MyClass(...){
}

//And my post-injection method
@Inject
private void postInjection(){
  Log.warn("Validator null? "+(validator==null));
}
```

**Problem** : The log shows `true` ( = validator is null, as if it had not been injected yet). Later, the validator is called on a button click and appears to be non-null. I tested with other injectable attributes and have the same problem.

**1)** Is there a common pattern to have a post injection method with Gin?

**2)** Is the injection order different with Gin in GWT? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in GIN up to 2.0, it's been fixed in 2.1.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/issues/detail?id=183